Fresh install crashing 24.04
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 "Fresh install" it is running as a VM on my unRaid server. I have Sonarr, Qbittorrent, and PIA installed (please don't judge). It will not run 8 hours without crashing. I have another instance exactly the same but running Radarr and it runs just fine. To get the VM back up and running I have to reboot. However I can login and I can access it after logging in. I just can't connect to any of the resources after the crash. Maybe it is better to call it a soft crash. But once the reboot happens I can access everything again for a limited time.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Link to logs
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v4BHIafIWu5DjtpakKuDRaoN98yW_nUQ/view?usp=sharing
Link has been updated for anyone to look at.
18:32:14 systemd: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
18:32:14 anacron: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
18:32:14 systemd: Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
18:30:28 Sonarr: SQLite error (5): database is locked in "PRAGMA cache_size=-20000"
18:30:02 systemd: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
18:30:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
18:28:41 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
18:28:31 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
18:28:31 systemd: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
18:28:30 NetworkManager: <info>  [1722983310.7071] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.196
18:27:58 Sonarr: SQLite error (5): database is locked in "PRAGMA cache_size=-20000"
18:25:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
18:25:01 kernel: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
18:25:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
18:21:54 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
18:21:44 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
18:21:43 systemd: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
18:21:43 NetworkManager: <info>  [1722982903.9378] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.196
18:20:06 systemd: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
18:19:01 gnome-character: JS LOG: Characters Application exiting
18:19:00 gnome-logs: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
18:18:58 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Logs'
18:18:51 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:51 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:50 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:50 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:49 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:49 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:49 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:49 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:48 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:48 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:48 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.seahorse.Application.desktop: Gio.DBusError: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
18:18:48 gnome-character: JS LOG: Characters Application started
18:18:47 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters'
18:18:47 nautilus: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
18:18:47 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:47 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
18:18:31 systemd: app-gnome-org.gnome.SystemMonitor-6210.scope: Consumed 2.496s CPU time.
18:18:30 gnome-character: JS LOG: Characters Application exiting
18:18:27 gnome-shell: Invalid sequence for VSYNC frame info
18:18:27 gnome-system-mo: libEGL warning: egl: failed to create dri2 screen
18:18:25 systemd: Started app-gnome-org.gnome.SystemMonitor-6210.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
18:18:20 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
18:18:20 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:20 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:20 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:20 nautilus: Source ID 180 was not found when attempting to remove it
18:18:20 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
18:18:20 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:20 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:18:17 gnome-character: JS LOG: Characters Application started
18:18:16 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Characters'
18:18:16 nautilus: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
18:18:16 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:16 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.clocks'
18:18:16 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:15 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Settings.SearchProvider'
18:18:15 gnome-shell: Received error from D-Bus search provider org.gnome.Terminal.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Cannot invoke method; proxy is for the well-known name org.gnome.Terminal without an owner, and proxy was constructed with the G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_DO_NOT_AUTO_START flag
18:18:15 dbus-daemon: [session uid=1000 pid=2859] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.33' (uid=1000 pid=3030 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell" label="unconfined")
18:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
18:17:01 kernel: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
18:17:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
18:16:23 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by alan(uid=1000)
18:16:14 systemd: Finished update-notifier-release.service - Notification regarding a new release of Ubuntu.
18:16:14 check-new-relea: WARNING:root:timeout reached, exiting
18:15:51 systemd: Starting update-notifier-release.service - Notification regarding a new release of Ubuntu...
18:15:49 systemd-logind: New session 6 of user alan.
18:15:49 sshd: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user alan(uid=1000) by alan(uid=0)
18:15:47 systemd: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
18:15:47 sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
18:15:47 systemd: Starting ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
18:15:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
18:14:53 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
18:14:43 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
18:14:43 systemd: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
18:14:42 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=825 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
18:14:42 NetworkManager: <info>  [1722982482.9658] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.196
18:10:06 systemd: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
18:09:52 Sonarr: [Info] RssSyncService: RSS Sync Completed. Reports found: 677, Reports grabbed: 0
18:08:22 systemd: Finished systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service - Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
18:07:42 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
18:07:42 systemd: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
18:07:42 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=825 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
18:07:42 NetworkManager: <info>  [1722982062.9245] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.196
18:05:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
18:05:01 kernel: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
18:05:01 cron: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by root(uid=0)
18:01:38 Sonarr: [Warn] DownloadedEpisodesImportService: Non-sample file detected: [/mnt/Temp/Rugrats (1991) Season 5 1080p/Rugrats (1991) S05E11 - Journey To The Center Of The Basement - A Very McNulty Birthday (1080p).mp4]
18:01:14 dbus-daemon: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
18:01:09 Sonarr: [Info] RecycleBinProvider: Recycling Bin has not been configured, deleting permanently. /mnt/TV/Rugrats/Season 5/Rugrats - S05E07 - Word of the Day HDTV-1080p.mp4
18:01:05 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
18:00:55 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
18:00:55 systemd: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
18:00:55 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=825 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
18:00:55 NetworkManager: <info>  [1722981655.6340] dhcp4 (enp1s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.1.196
18:00:52 systemd: Started fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon.
18:00:52 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
18:00:52 fwupd: 22:00:52.644 FuMain               Daemon ready for requests (locale en_US.UTF-8)
18:00:49 systemd: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth).
18:00:49 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.90' (uid=0 pid=5299 comm="/usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd" label="unconfined")
18:00:49 systemd: Starting fwupd.service - Firmware update daemon...
18:00:49 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.89' (uid=1000 pid=5238 comm="/snap/firmware-updater/127/bin/firmware-notifier" label="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier (enforce)")
18:00:49 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1722981649.470:157): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=5238 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
18:00:49 systemd: tmp-snap.rootfs_a9iscH.mount: Deactivated successfully.
18:00:49 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1722981649.054:155): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=5238 comm="snap-confine" capability=38  capname="perfmon"
18:00:49 systemd: Started snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier.service - Service for snap application firmware-updater.firmware-notifier.
18:00:41 Sonarr: [Info] RecycleBinProvider: Recycling Bin has not been configured, deleting permanently. /mnt/TV/Rugrats/Season 5/Rugrats - S05E02 - Sleep Trouble HDTV-1080p.mp4
18:00:06 systemd: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
17:59:46 Sonarr: [Info] RecycleBinProvider: Recycling Bin has not been configured, deleting permanently. /mnt/TV/Rugrats/Season 5/Rugrats - S05E04 - Chuckie Grows HDTV-1080p.mp4
17:59:06 systemd: launchpadlib-cache-clean.service - Clean up old files in the Launchpadlib cache was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/home/alan/.launchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache).
17:58:50 Sonarr: [Info] Auth: Auth-Success ip 192.168.1.120 username 'alan'
17:58:41 systemd: packagekit.service: Deactivated successfully.
17:58:41 packagekitd: daemon quit
17:58:38 Sonarr: [Info] Sonarr.Http.Authentication.BasicAuthenticationHandler: AuthenticationScheme: Basic was challenged.
17:58:37 systemd: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
17:58:31 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
17:58:31 systemd: Starting systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service...
17:58:31 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.21' (uid=0 pid=783 comm="/usr/lib/snapd/snapd" label="unconfined")
17:58:27 systemd: Started NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
17:58:27 dbus-daemon: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
17:58:27 systemd: Starting NetworkManager-dispatcher.service - Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
17:58:27 dbus-daemon: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.12' (uid=0 pid=825 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon" label="unconfined")
17:58:27 NetworkManager: <info>  [1722981507.0618] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
17:58:26 systemd: Finished update-notifier-download.service - Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
17:58:21 Sonarr: [Info] RecycleBinProvider: Recycling Bin has not been configured, deleting permanently. /mnt/TV/Rugrats/Season 5/Rugrats - S05E01 - Babysitting Fluffy HDTV-1080p.mp4
17:57:05 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
17:57:05 kernel:  </TASK>
17:57:05 kernel: Call Trace:
17:57:05 kernel: PKRU: 55555554
17:57:05 kernel: CR2: 000076cf59984000 CR3: 0000000107080000 CR4: 0000000000750ef0
17:57:05 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
17:57:05 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa0f195580000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
17:57:05 kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffa0ef856b50c0 R15: ffffa0f1955b4500
17:57:05 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffc0729570
17:57:05 kernel: RBP: ffffb7ec81397c68 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
17:57:05 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
17:57:05 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffa0ef801cf600 RCX: 0000000000000000
17:57:05 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb7ec81397c48 EFLAGS: 00010046
17:57:05 kernel: Code: 56 18 4d 89 e0 48 8d 8b b0 00 00 00 48 c7 c7 a0 f7 25 93 c6 05 7e d1 6c 02 01 48 8b 70 08 48 81 c6 b0 00 00 00 e8 d1 5a fd ff <0f> 0b e9 b2 fe ff ff 44 0f b6 2d 60 d1 6c 02 41 80 fd 01 77 0f 41
17:57:05 kernel: RIP: 0010:check_flush_dependency+0x16f/0x1a0
17:57:05 kernel: Workqueue: ttm ttm_bo_delayed_delete [ttm]
17:57:05 kernel: Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (Q35 + ICH9, 2009), BIOS unknown 2/2/2022
17:57:05 kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 867 Comm: kworker/u9:3 Not tainted 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu


The link to logs requires permission to access.

You can see the log entries just before the last crash with sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e. Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.

Link has been updated for anyone to look at.

@waltinator I know enough to be dangerous. I ran your command and didn't see anything that stood out to me. Can you advise what I should be looking for in general?
